# Is there a limit to the number of magic rings a character can wear on one hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I know that in previous editions you could only have one magic ring per hand, is that true in 5th edition (RAW) as well?

Comment: It matters quite a bit as there's a general limit as to how many attunement-required items you can attune to at any one time

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The rules that answer this can be found on page 141 of the DMG, under the heading "Multiple Items of the Same Kind".

> Use common sense to determine whether more than one of a given kind of magic item can be worn.
>
> You can make exceptions; a character might
> be able to wear a circlet under a helmet, for example, or
> be able to layer two cloaks.

Like many parts of the 5th edition rules, this was left up to the DM. The guidelines in that section make it pretty clear that the only real restriction to how many (non-attuned) magic items of a type you can wear is how many you can physically fit on your body.

There are no rules that I can find that say that rings would be an exception to this, and many rings don't require attunement. You can still only attune three items at a time, but you can wear as many non-attuned rings as you can fit on your fingers.

Answer (score 30):

### You may benefit from (wear) seven magic rings at one time, barring duplicates.

*Note: since this question is tagged RAW, I am limiting it to the official rings listed in the DMG.*

There is no limit to the number of rings, magical or not, that your character can wear. There *is* a limit to the number of rings you can benefit from, if you are not homebrewing any rules or magic items.

Of the 25 rings listed in the DMG, all but four require attunement. The others are:

- Ring of Swimming
- Ring of Water Walking
- Ring of Animal Influence
- Ring of Three Wishes

The first two do not stack or improve upon each other in any meaningful way. The Ring of Animal Influence has charges. You could have multiples of this, switching to the next when you have expended charges from the previous. The same holds true for the Ring of Three Wishes, although these do not recharge.

Beyond those four, you are limited by the number to which you can attune. The 5e rules allow you to attune to a maximum of three items at any given time. Therefore, you can benefit from (the most meaningful sense of "wear") the four rings listed above, plus any three others requiring attunement, with the caveat that if you had duplicates of the Ring of Three Wishes or Ring of Animal control, you could increase the number heyond seven.

Comment: Cute. But RAW is _The magic items in chapter 7, "Treasure," section are but a few of the magic treasures that characters can discover during their adventures_.

Comment: Funny, all this time I never suspected RAW stood for "Rings As Written." Learn something every day =)

Comment: @mattdm Although this is true, I was confining myself to only the rings as written, as nitsua60 puts it. :) Since any number of magic items could be created by a DM, including one that allows infinite attunements, I felt compelled to constrain myself to the ones expressly written in the DMG.

Answer (score 8):

***There are no restrictions beyond using common sense as to how many rings you can wear*.**

This means you may wear a magical ring on each available finger, with the following restrictions, which apply to all magic items:

- You cannot attune to two more than one copy of an item, with the specific example given in the rules of two rings of protection. You only get the benefit(s) from the one you are attuned to
- You are restricted the the limit of three attuned items (unless you use certain Unearthed Arcana classes)
- You are subject to any class, race or other restrictions specific to the rings
- If two benefits from different rings are from the same *spell effect* you gain only the most potent effect

The rules covering this are quoted below:

Multiple Items of the Same Kind (DMG p.141)

> Use common sense to determine whether more than one of a given kind of magic item can be worn.

Attunement (DMG p.137)

> a creature can be attuned to no more than three magic items at a time.
>
> a creature can't attune to more than one copy of an item. For example, a creature can't attune to more than one ring of protection at a time.

Combining Magical Effects (PHB p.206)

> The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap.

Comment: In real life people sometimes wear more than one decorative ring on the same finger. Your DM is free to say that magic rings can't be worn like that (or don't work if they are), but they could equally well impose other restrictions (e.g. "only one per hand", or even "only one"). Or they might allow toe rings as well as finger rings.