# How many rings that have special effects can one character wear at a time while still having all of the special effects

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

So i was wondering how many magical rings can one character wear at once while still retaining their special effects.

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111523/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-magic-rings-a-character-can-wear-on-one-hand

Comment: Should we assume all rings do not require attunement? If so, then the above is a duplicate.

Comment: yes the rings do not require attunement